# What is this c. 1930 beautiful monoplane seen in Oakland?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

Photo from Denny Wright's album.  He piloted for 
Clyde Sunderland.  This photo has no stamp or markings. Anyone recognize this aircraft?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any more info about the image or Denny Wright himself? Can't really find anything about either.

Comment: It looks similar to the Hughes H-1 Racer but the difference is that the H-1's landing gear is further apart and folds towards the fuselage whereas this aircraft's landing gear appears to be non-retractable.

Comment: I am going with the Lockhead, due to looks and dates.  The Big plane, right background, is a Western Air Express Folker F-32, NC333N or NC334N (there were two).  The second from the right is Wright's "Whirlwind Waco" (?), NC935K.

Comment: Mistake in above comment: the background small monoplane is a "Travel Air six passenger with Wright Whirlwind motor", belonging to Wright Air Service.

Comment: I didn't say it was the Hughes H-1. Just that it looked very similar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lockheed_Sirius_Paul_Mantz.jpg))

It looks like the [**Lockheed Model 8 Sirius**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Model_8_Sirius), or a variant of it.

First flight was 1929, and 15 were built.

> Two versions of the same basic design were built for the United States Air Force, one made largely of wood with a fixed landing gear, and one with a metal skin and retractable landing gear, designated Y1C-25 and Y1C-23, respectively. Its basic role was intended to be as a utility transport.